# Selenium Java - How to click on an element without having it ID?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, web

I'm trying to click in a radio button by it's Xpath or Id.
I inspected the element with Google Developer Tool and was able to get below details:

1. Element Name: `<label for="1346_Voltagem_0"
   class="dimension-Voltagem espec_0 skuespec_110v
   skuespec_Voltagem_opcao_110V
   skuespec_Voltagem_opcao_110v">110V</label>`
2. Xpath:
   `/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/span/label[1]`

I would like to know how to say to the code that it has to click on that radiobutton?

[Click here](http://loja.consul.com.br/geladeira-consul-frost-free-386-litros-evox-crm42nk/p) for the page  where I want to click the radioButton. Also, please refer the below screenshot for the exact element

[image: actual image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using absolute xpaths as a small change in the UI will cause a lot of changes to be made in your code.
For your question, the following xpaths will work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='110V']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'110v')]")).click();
```

Comment: Glad it did ! Kindly consider upvoting answers if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='skuselector-specification-label input-dimension-Voltagem sku-selector skuespec_110v change-image']")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `xpath` for this since you need to find the `label` and then find the previous input to it

You can find the label using

```
//div[contains(@class,'prod-sku-selector')]//label[.='110V']
```

and now to get the previous `input` you can use

```
//div[contains(@class,'prod-sku-selector')]//label[.='110V']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

[image: css selector]

Answer (score -1):

I always believe that xpath should not be much dependent on your html divs and hierarchy as that is very easy to fail even with a smallest change. So, using xPath like "/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/span/label[1]" is not a good option.

In this case, I would suggest you to go with below xpath:

If first radio button needs to be clicked:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'prod-sku-selector')]//input[@type='radio'][1]
```

If radio button with value 110v needs to be clicked:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'prod-sku-selector')]//input[contains(@value, '110V')]
```

Then you can get element using :

```
radioBtn1 = findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'prod-sku-selector')]//input[@type='radio'][0]"));
```

Also, you can click radio in selenium using:

```
radioBtn1.click();
```

Comment: The xpath isn't correct. `[0]` is not a valid index. It should start from `[1]`. Also you should try to identify control using some reference and not just indexes. Because if `110V` option is taken off then this would just blindly select the `220V` one without raising an issue

Comment: Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMhn7.png). The xpath `//div[contains(@class, 'prod-sku-selector')]//input[@type='radio'][0]` you listed earlier doesn't work

Comment: I have updated the index in my answer. For the second point related to 110v, that totally depends upon the requirement, if first radio button needs to be clicked, the above option will work or else if specific 110v needs to be clicked, the below xpath can be used: //div[contains(@class, 'prod-sku-selector')]//input[contains(@value, '110V')]. The whole motive of this platform is to help the people and not spoon feed them