# xpath is validated but getting "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to open the calendar and click the month. I can manage to open up the calendar but my xpath for the calendar isnt being recognized. I validated that my xpath works in the chrome console but its only able to validate it once the calendar is opened. Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

[image]
        `

```
`import java.util.List;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

 public class CalendarExample {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\Selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");

    List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.className("day"));
    String text = "";


    //select August 22 from calendar
    //step 1: open the calendar
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='travel_date']")).click();

    //step 2: click the month 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table//th[@class='datepicker-switch']")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: please ensure that element is visible at the time you are trying to get the element by xpath

Comment: can you please share the URL if possible where you are trying to implement the test

Comment: My element was [under a shadow root and I had to use a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow).

Answer (score 1):

In selenium, an element object is returned only when the element is visible in the browser. On the other hand, if the element is not visible, **Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException** is returned. So, looking at the issue you shared, it is possible that the calendar elements are being created only when its open, so at the time you are trying to click on calendar, you have to ensure the calendar is open. Only then, the element will be returned.

PS: One suggestion of what kind of XPath you should use, Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497529/1262248

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to tell it to wait until the webpage loaded. i just put a "Thread.sleep(5000);" after the "driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");"

Comment: right... its better to add it as an answer to your question so that other ending with the same issue have an idea how to solve it

Comment: Thread.sleep(5000) is not a great idea. Use waits provided by Selenium API https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Answer (score 0):

You experience your error because you are trying to access an element before it is available in `DOM`.
So just first open calendar and after that access element with class "day".
No need to change your `xpath`.

```
//open calendar
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='travel_date']")).click();

//access element with class "day"
List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.className("day"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is not visible when you are trying to click it.

Declare this at the start of your class:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
```

Then, before you click the element insert this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//body/div[4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table//th[@class='datepicker-switch']")));
```

Hope this helps.