# Handle Print Preview window using selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to stream print preview which is displayed in print dialog.

[print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN9ER.png)

Is their any way to stream print preview generated without saving it,so that i can directly parse/use that text in my code using selenium

Comment: Do you want to read the content from Print Preview? If yes, then what data you want to read? you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562264/handle-print-preview-window-using-selenium-in-chrome-latest-version/56563890#56563890) to click on the cancel button on the print-preview.

Comment: Yes,i want to read content from print preview and i want to use that content in my code e.g to validate the content present on that preview

Comment: Have you tried save as pdf and then validate?

Comment: Yes,But now i want to use it without saving it.

Comment: so, you want to read the pdf directly from the webpage rather from pdf stored on physical location... let me think.

Comment: Hi @supputuri did you find any work around to do it.?

Comment: Sorry, for the delayed replay. Unfortunately, the content is in embed pdf. So it's not possible to read the content from print preview pdf directly. You might have to download it to validate.