# Selenium-Python: Unable to clear chrome browser cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to clear chrome browser cache by click on the 'Clear data' button below after navigating to chrome://settings/clearBrowserData. But I'm unable to click on the 'Clear data' button. Please advise.

[image]

**I'm using:**

**Operating System:** Win 10 pro 64bit

**python version:** 3.6.1

**Chrome Version:** 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
def clear_current_session(self):

    # Opens a new tab
    self.driver.execute_script("window.open()")

    # Switch to the newly opened tab
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])

    # Navigate to new URL in new tab
    self.driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")

    #Click on the Clear data button
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm").click()

    self.driver.implicitly_wait(60)

    # Switch to original tab
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: There's an error?  What happens?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the script where javascript will return the clearButton element and then clicks using python selenium.

```
clearButton = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-section > settings-privacy-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataDialog').querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataConfirm')")
#click on the clear button now
clearButton.click()
```

Check my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the ".click()" at the end of the line:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]").click()
```

Comment: Wrongly copied the code updated it now still its not working.

Comment: Have you tried using "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]").click()" ?

Comment: Yes it wont work. I tried the solution in the below link but it didn't work. https://intoli.com/blog/clear-the-chrome-browser-cache/