# python selenium, can't find elements from page_source while can find from browser

Tags: python, selenium

I try find target element by xpath so that I can click on it. But can't find it when run code, although can find it by right-click option manually on chrome browser.

detail: I am using

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
```

to get history pop-up from chrome, then wait element by selenium, 
and next action I try to click it by:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm').click()
```

or by:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//paper-button[@id="clearBrowsingDataConfirm"]').click()
```

both does not work

Could you tell solution by xpath if possible because I am more familiar with it. Or any other way to clear history on chrome, thank

Comment: check `driver.page_source` - browser may not give access to settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)

Comment: The above link will give the detailed explanation of the issue and solution. Check it out and upvote if you feel the answer is helpful :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looking into Chrome Settings page source it looks like the button, you're looking for is hidden in the [ShadowDOM](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+Mobile+Web+Testing+On+Chrome+With+Android)

So you need to iterate down several levels of [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)

[image]

So the algorithm looks like:

1. Locate parent [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)
2. Locate its `shadow-root` and cast it to the WebElement
3. Use [WebElement.find_element()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) function to locate the next WebElement which is the parent for the ShadowRoot
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until you're in the same context with the element you want to interact with

Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def expand_root_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root


driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\apps\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")

settingsUi = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("settings-ui")
settingsUiShadowRoot = expand_root_element(settingsUi)

settingsMain = settingsUiShadowRoot.find_element_by_tag_name("settings-main")
settingsShadowRoot = expand_root_element(settingsMain)
settingsBasicPage = settingsShadowRoot.find_element_by_tag_name("settings-basic-page")
settingsBasicPageShadowroot = expand_root_element(settingsBasicPage)
settingsPrivacyPage = settingsBasicPageShadowroot.find_element_by_tag_name("settings-privacy-page")
settingsPrivacyShadowRoot = expand_root_element(settingsPrivacyPage)
settingsClearBrowsingDataDialog = settingsPrivacyShadowRoot.find_element_by_tag_name(
    "settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog")
settingsClearBrowsingDataDialogShadowRoot = expand_root_element(settingsClearBrowsingDataDialog)
settingsClearBrowsingDataDialogShadowRoot.find_element_by_id("clearBrowsingDataConfirm").click()
```

Comment: The code is work, thank.  Other Question:  How do I print the '''WebElements of    settingsClearBrowsingDataDialogShadowRoot'''?  I did try  '''settingsClearBrowsingDataDialogShadowRoot.get_attribute('innerHTML')'''  but it doesn't look like HTML format.  Another Question, I see that you find the final elements by    find_element_by_id  , is any way can find inner html by xpath, I did by using   '''find_element_by_xpath'''  , but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
 driver.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('body > settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('#main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('#advancedPage > settings-section:nth-child(1) > settings-privacy-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('#clearBrowsingDataConfirm').click();");
```

Comment: you can explain your answer, i.e. what the code you added does? to make your answer clear