# Double click failed with org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to double click on an element hence have following code -

```
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.doubleClick(visibleElement).perform();
```

But for double click, it results into -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion
```

I googled it a lot but did not get what is cause of this and how to resolve this. Could you please help with this?

Comment: Don’t know your use case.However if you click twice on the element it doesn’t work?

Comment: Try this one `builder.moveToElement(visibleElement).doubleClick(visibleElement).build().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion
```

...implies that the `GetElementRegion()` method failed to parse the value.

---

### Deep dive

This error is coming from [element_util.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/element_util.cc#577):

```
Status GetElementRegion(
    Session* session,
    WebView* web_view,
    const std::string& element_id,
    WebRect* rect) {
  Status status = CheckElement(element_id);
  if (status.IsError())
    return status;
  base::ListValue args;
  args.Append(CreateElement(element_id));
  std::unique_ptr<base::Value> result;
  status = web_view->CallFunction(
      session->GetCurrentFrameId(), kGetElementRegionScript, args, &result);
  if (status.IsError())
    return status;
  if (!ParseFromValue(result.get(), rect)) {
    return Status(kUnknownError,
          "failed to parse value of getElementRegion");
  }
  return Status(kOk);
}
```

---

### Reasons and Solutions

There can be diverse reasons and solutions to this error as follows:

- Ensure the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) for **visibleElement** identifies the element uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes)
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` before you invoke `doubleClick()` as follows:

  ```
  new Actions(driver).doubleClick(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(visibleElement))).perform();
  ```
- Add the `build()` step:

  ```
  new Actions(driver).doubleClick(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(visibleElement))).build().perform();
  ```
- Before you try to invoke `doubleClick()` from *Actions* Class ensure that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) have the focus within the correct **Frame** i.e. either the *Top Level View* or an `<iframe>` element.

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

- Ensure that the element is not within any [#shadow-root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector) or [shadow-dom](/questions/tagged/shadow-dom).

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)