# access shadowDOM with Selenium/Java/JMeter/chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, shadow-dom

Using Selenium/Java/JMeter/chromedriver - Am trying to access elements in a shadowDOM page with roots nested on several levels using `return arguments[0].shadowRoot`. However am getting the error below:

```
Error in method invocation: Method executeScript( java.lang.String, org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10);

WDS.browser.get("contentPage");
//checks/waits, switchtoFrame
WebElement root1 = WDS.browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("launcher"));
//confirming find successful
WDS.log.info("Found: " + root1.getAttribute("href"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) WDS.browser;  
jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", root1);
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow/56381495#56381495) answer which have detailed explanation how to work with shadow elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

It looks like you're using [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) which isn't really `java`, so make sure to choose `groovy` as the scripting language for the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)

[image]

and once done you should be able to normally use your existing code.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)