# How to traverse to an element which is inside a Shadow DOM using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, shadow-dom

I want to get shadow element using text "ShadowRootLabel" from below code :

```
<div id="example">
#shadow-root
<div id="root" part="root">
  <div id="label" part="label">ShadowRootLabel</div>
</div>
</ptcs-label>
```

Comment: Which Selenium clients are you using Java/Python/NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

To identify the [shadow-dom](/questions/tagged/shadow-dom) element using the text **ShadowRootLabel** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you can use the following [java](/questions/tagged/java) based solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebElement root = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#example"));
  WebElement shadow_root = expand_shadow_element(root);
  WebElement ShadowRootLabel = shadow_root.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='root']/div[text()='ShadowRootLabel']"));
  ```
- `expand_shadow_element()` method:

  ```
  public static WebElement expand_shadow_element(WebElement element)
  {
      WebElement shadowRoot = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
      return shadowRoot;
  }
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)
- [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)