# Getting "Nosuch element Exception" in Selenium Though XPATH is correct. Not sure is this due to Shadow DOM. Please confirm

Tags: selenium, xpath, ui-automation, shadow-dom

I am trying to automate Salesforce application Using Selenium and getting `NoSuchelementException` though XPATH is correct and valid for particular object. When i have searched the issue, it might be reason for Shadow DOM.

For EX:

So XAPTH i have written like,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Name']")).sendKeys("Jams");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input-299']")).sendKeys("Jams");
```

This XPATH is highlighting in Console as well. But while automating it throws nosuchelement error.

So while checking for ShadowDOM option, am getting option like this for Name Object.

```
#shadow-root(user-agent)
```

Shadowroot DIV

[image]

-- nothing mentioned in div. it just open and closed tags.

How to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there are any iframes in your Dom. Simply do `//iframe` in your page developer mode(F12)> elements tab > search (Ctrf+F) area. If there are any, you will get the number of iframes.

Now if your textbox is in any of iframe use below code to go inside particular iframe first

```
driver.switch_to.frame("<name or Id of frame>")
```

then come out to frame use below:

```
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

**Also,** if the issue is not related to frames check below for shadow-root related issue:

you can check below for shadow-root element ( Question is for Java, but you can co-relate):

[How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)

Answer (score 0):

The website contents are mostly created now using javascript. You may have to wait for certain elements to load before doing anything to it.

https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/wait