# Locate element with selenium Xpath for date picker drop-down menu in Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, datetimepicker

I wanted to click on the date in the dropdown datepicker. Bus the error occurs **Unable to Locate Element**. I tried :

`monyear = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]').click()`

and

`element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]")))`

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

But none of them worked for me. **Please suggest the possible solutions for it**. Here is the HTML code and image of the dopbox.

```
<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu" style="display: block; top: 311.969px; left: 627.406px;">
 <div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
  <table class=" table-condensed">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="prev">‹</th>
     <th colspan="5" class="switch">August 2020</th>
     <th class="next">›</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th class="dow">Su</th>
     <th class="dow">Mo</th>
     ...........
     <th class="dow">Sa</th>
    </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
   ............
   <tr>
    <td class="day  active">23</td>
    <td class="day ">24</td>
    <td class="day ">25</td>
    <td class="day ">26</td>
    <td class="day ">27</td>
    <td class="day ">28</td>
    <td class="day ">29</td></tr>
   <tr>
```

[image]

I found these two frames:

```
<iframe src="chrome-extension://kdfieneakcjfaiglcfcgkidlkmlijjnh/writer/index.html"></iframe>
<iframe class="ginger-banner-frame" style="width:385px;height:85px;" ng-src="https://cdn.gingersoftware.com/banners/default/chromeextension.writer.underTools.html" src="https://cdn.gingersoftware.com/banners/default/chromeextension.writer.underTools.html"></iframe>
```

These might be of chrome extensions. Do they have any effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing absolute xPath why can you right more short and easy to debug relative xpth. Some thing like

```
date = 19 # You can choose any date
dateXpath = "//td[contains(@Class,'day') and text()="+str(date)+"]"


# Clicking on calendar input
driver.find_element_by_id('startDateToday').click()

# Clicking on Date
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, dateXpath))).click()

# Bug with page, as after clicking on date calendar is not closing. So clicking outside
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(),'Total Rows')]"))).click()
```

**Note :**

1. I am assuming your date picker is in same frame as your page. If there is a separate iFrame you need to handle accordingly. [Getting "Nosuch element Exception" in Selenium Though XPATH is correct. Not sure is this due to Shadow DOM. Please confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546935/getting-nosuch-element-exception-in-selenium-though-xpath-is-correct-not-sure/63547744#63547744)
2. Above solution is with assumption that you want to click date from current open month/year ( In this case August, 2020). In case you want to change different Month/ year, you have to identify respective elements accordingly and make amendments in your code.

Comment: There is no such frame (as you can also see in html above) and the relative path also shows the similar error. What might be the reason?

Comment: Your xpath is not identifying any date. Try with xpath I have provided in Answer section.

Comment: I tried the same but still is not working. Similar problem: TimeoutException message

Comment: There are not any frames in the section above the body part of the HTML. When I searched <frame there are 2 matches but both seem to be unassociated with the page, Are those considered to be frames??

Comment: How can I select the specific date and month with the automation in datepicker table

Comment: Please use edited Answer. There was one small issue with earlier code as there was extra s in class and C was in small alphabet instead of C. Above will help you choose any date from open month. Also there is a bug in the page as after clicking on date calendar is not closing that's why last line was needed.

Comment: Does this require the line to wait for the page to load

Comment: Now I will try how to change the Month and year.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers!!! Yes you can try now chnaging month and year. Let me know any issue.