# Python Selenium - How to locate and add data in textarea which is under #shadow-root (open)

Tags: python, selenium, textarea, shadow-dom, queryselector

I am trying to locate and enter data in the text area for below code.

But it does not locate the element.

HTML :

```
    <label _ngcontent-c8="" class="form__label form__label--bottom" for="description ">
        <span _ngcontent-c8="" class="form__label-inner-wrap"> Product description <span _ngcontent-c8="" aria-label="required">*
        </span></span>
    </label>
    <eds-textarea _ngcontent-c8="" id="productDescTextArea" maxlength="1000" name="description" ng-version="9.1.13">
        #shadow-root (open)
        <style>....</style>
        <style>...</style>
        <div class="textarea">
            <textarea class="textarea__input u-mb--" placeholder="Please provide a detail description of product." rows="4">
            </textarea>
            <span id="textarea-character-counter" class="textarea__counter">Characters Available: 
                <span aria-atomic="false" aria-live="true" aria-relevant="text">1000/1000
                </span>
            </span>
        <!----></div>
    </eds-textarea>
</div>
```

I tried CSS Locator:

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea")
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[placeholder='Please provide a detail description of product.']").send
```

Also XPATH:

```
//textarea[@placeholder='Please provide a detail description of product.']
```

Could not locate the element - Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root = driver.find_element_by_id("productDescTextArea")

textarea = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('textarea[placeholder=\"Please provide a detail description of product.\"]')",root)
```

you have to call the shadowRoot and then find element using querySelector

Comment: Thank you for the quick response . I tried the same : which generated an error. ```raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list ```

Comment: Also, How would Add data in the text field. I tried this,``` textarea.send_keys("DATA") ```, but seems like send_keys can not be used here.

Comment: Did you escape nthe double quotes ,

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `<textarea>` is within a [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector).

```
<eds-textarea _ngcontent-c8="" id="productDescTextArea" maxlength="1000" name="description" ng-version="9.1.13">
    #shadow-root (open)
    <style>....</style>
    <style>...</style>
    <div class="textarea">
        <textarea class="textarea__input u-mb--" placeholder="Please provide a detail description of product." rows="4">
        </textarea>
        <span id="textarea-character-counter" class="textarea__counter">Characters Available: 
            <span aria-atomic="false" aria-live="true" aria-relevant="text">1000/1000
            </span>
        </span>
    <!----></div>
</eds-textarea>
```

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* with in the `<textarea>` field you have to use [`shadowRoot.querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#productDescTextArea').shadowRoot.querySelector('textarea.textarea__input[placeholder^="Please provide a detail description of product"]')""")
  element.send_keys("Apeksha Mehta")
  ```