# Unable to click pdf download button buried in #shadow-root (open) with Selenium in python using JavaScript Locator

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a webscraper to automate document download. The button is buried within multiple shadow roots. I suspect the issue lies with my webdriver's current loaded page. I'm fairly certain I need to use JavaScript to drill through the `shadow-roots`, but I'm not sure.

I keep getting this error: `JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')`

Here's my complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/or_sch_1.asp"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="window1"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a').click()

doc_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="window2"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/font[2]/input')
doc_type.send_keys('D')

consideration_input = driver.find_element_by_name('consideration')
consideration_input.send_keys('5,000,000')

from_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="window2"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font[3]/input')

from_date.clear()
from_date.send_keys('11/04/2021')

to_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="window2"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font[5]/input')

to_date.clear()
to_date.send_keys('11/05/2021')

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="window2"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/input[2]')
submit_button.click()

url_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("list_2[href]")
url_list[0].click()

driver.switch_to.frame('FrmDes')

image_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/map[4]/area")
image_button.click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame('FrmImg')
view_pdf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/form/input[12]')
view_pdf.click()

try:
    driver.page_source
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

element = driver.execute_script(
    "return document.querySelector('pdf-viewer').shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-download-controls')"
)
```

Comment: Are you reffering to `view_pdf` button  ? I do not see that it is in shadow root

Comment: I think the query is not correct. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow/56381495#56381495 and make sure you are able to access the element in the browser console first.