# how to get control for start building option in servicenow login page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i wants to get the control for (start building) option in servicenow login page. i have tried something but its not working.kindly help me in this case.

IWebElement ele3= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@type='button'][text()='[Start Building']")); ele3.Click();

[image]

when i click inspect it shows this, not able to capture class, id or name.

This is the sample code i done for login to servicenow:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

```
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Url = "https://developer.servicenow.com";
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    var query = "return document.querySelector('dps-app').shadowRoot";
    query += ".querySelector('dps-navigation-header').shadowRoot";
    query += ".querySelector('dps-login').shadowRoot";
    query += ".querySelector('dps-button')";
    IWebElement elt = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(query);
    elt.Click();wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("username"))).SendKeys("email@toto.fr");
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("usernameSubmitButton"))).Click();
    var but = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("submitButton")));
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("password");
    but.Click();
```

Comment: Can you share the login page URL here if possible? It will help people to replicate your issue

Comment: This is the url (https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/home), i have done the login part passing email and password and sign in that is done after that needs to click on start building for that iam searching commands in c#

Comment: Now you will have to share the DOM where that element is appearing. You can do it by : CTRIL+SHIFT+I (Open developer tool) in browser-> Mouse hover to that element-> Right click-<Inspect Element . Whatever appears, share that here.  Other people wouldn't be able to help you without that.

Comment: (<button class="dps-button -round -md has-action -external-action has-button-and-icon" label="Start Building " size="md" icon=""><span>Start Building </span><now-icon icon="arrow-up-right-fill" now-id="zi2tzivwlyd4" component-id="zi2tzivwlyd4" dir="ltr"></now-icon></button>). this is the one i found i have used class but it not working it shows no such element found.

Comment: Can you check with this xpath: //button[@label='Start Building ']//span .

Comment: (xpath:) is showing error while typing.

Comment: (IWebElement ele4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath: // button[@label='Start Building']//span);
ele4.Click();). i have tried this but its showing error.

Comment: This element is inside shadow root, that's why it is not clicking on it. Please refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor js1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var query1 = "return document.querySelector('dps-app').shadowRoot";
query1 += ".querySelector('dps-home-auth-quebec').shadowRoot";
query1 += ".querySelector('dps-page-header').shadowRoot";
IWebElement elt1 = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(query);
elt1.Click(); -i have tried this but its not working could someone help me in this case.

Comment: Do you have a demo credentials handy for test?

Comment: @LydiaSahayam did you get the solution with the help of relevant links?

Comment: @DebanjanB:i have attached the sample code i done for login after that i wnats to click on start building but this part showing error using shadow root also.kindly help me

Comment: @QualityMatters:i have attached the code which i tried using shadowroot links but its showing error.

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor js1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; var query1 = "return document.querySelector('dps-app').shadowRoot"; query1 += ".querySelector('dps-home-auth-quebec').shadowRoot"; query1 += ".querySelector('span').shadowRoot"; IWebElement elt1 = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(query); elt1.Click();- when i tried this i got a (object reference not set to an insance of an object.)

Comment: I have a python code working fine. for your issue Let me convert it to C# one. Or let me know if you can do it by your own. I can share python snippet here

Comment: sure pls share if possible can you share it as c# code.many thanks

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor js1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var query1 = "return document.querySelector('dps-app').shadowRoot";
query1 += ".querySelector('dps-home-auth-quebec').shadowRoot";
query1 += ".querySelector('dps-home-section-content.-header').shadowRoot";
query1 += ".querySelector('dps-page-header').shadowRoot";
query1 += ".querySelector('dps-button.-round.-md.has-action.-external-action.has-button-and-icon')";
IWebElement elt1 = (IWebElement)js1.ExecuteScript(query1);
elt1.Click(); -i tried this still getting error

Comment: can i get an ans pls.

Comment: This worked in C#:  driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton")).Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000*20);
            IWebElement startButtonElement = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('dps-app[now-id]').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > main > dps-home-auth-quebec').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > section:nth-child(1) > div > dps-page-header > div:nth-child(1) > button > span')");
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
          startButtonElement.Click();

Comment: Let me know if above code doesn't work

Comment: Thanks much i got my output.Thanks for the help@QualityMatters

Comment: Hii@quality matters at first time when i run the code it successfully runs but sencond time when i run this code its showing object reference not set to an instance of an object.could you help me in this case?

Comment: May be you have done some changes. Just copy paste again.

Comment: its working now,thanks much for the help.