# Best way to click a button within #shadow-root (open) via Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-dom, queryselector, shadow-root

I am currently dabbling in Python in combination with Selenium. Here I came across the topic of Java Script buttons. I am looking for the smartest way to find out how to execute a Java-Script code (in this case a button) the easiest way.

My goals:

1. Open web page http://www.easyCredit.de
2. Accept the Cockies there
3. Click the "Jetzt berechnen" button
4. Click the "Zu den finanziellen Angaben" button

Number 1 and 2, I got right with a lot of research. Now it's time to click the button. This can be identified quite well in the code, but still I do not succeed in clicking.

```
<input type="submit" class="calculator__submit-button" value="calculate now">
```

I have now tried it similar to the cockies, but unfortunately it does not work. I hope you can help me.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

# link to Chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

# maximize window
browser.maximize_window()

# URL
browser.get('https://www.easycredit.de/')

# wait
time.sleep(5)

# accept cookies
coockie_button = browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
coockie_button.click()

# wait
time.sleep(5)

# click "Jetzt berechnen" 
berechnen_button = browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('rr-62f0ff69f069c').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[class='calculator__submit-button']")""")
berechnen_button.click()
```

The last part does not work.

This is the button I want to click:

[image]

Comment: Which is that **Zu den finanziellen Angaben** button?

Comment: My next goal is the "Jetzt berechnen" Button. I added a Screenshot.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to click the button on the next page (Zu den finanziellen Angaben)? There it somehow does not work with this method.

Comment: Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Jetzt berechnen</kbd> is within [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector) and is an *`<input>`* element.

[image: Jetzt]

---

### Solution

To click on <kbd>Jetzt berechnen</kbd> you can use the following line of code:

```
berechnen_button = browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('kredit-rechner').shadowRoot.querySelector('input.calculator__submit-button')""")
berechnen_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank You. Did you test the code? I get "JavascriptException: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.79)"

Comment: My bad, there was a typo, fixed it. Let me know the results.

Comment: Thank You. So I can go for the next Button to try :)

Comment: @edstrinova yeap, ofcoarse :)

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to click the button on the next page? There it somehow does not work with this method.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium 4 introduced a new way to access shadow DOM elements: 
`shadow_root=elem.shadow_root`

```py
shadow_root = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "kredit-rechner").shadow_root
berechnen_button = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.calculator__submit-button")
berechnen_button.click()
```

Safe solution:

```
shadow_root = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "kredit-rechner"))).shadow_root
WebDriverWait(shadow_root, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input.calculator__submit-button"))).click()
```

Comment: This works perfectly