# Webdriver.io: Input text/value on shadow element not working in web application using chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, shadow-root

Webdriver.io: Input text/value on shadow element not working in web application using chrome browser

I am using webdriver io for automating web application. Please refer below screenshot which is opened after click action. And I have to enter value in the textbox which is inside of nested shadow elements-

[image]

Solution Tried-

1. I tried to input text using shadow element

   status=await driver.execute("document.querySelector('csv-header-desktop').shadowRoot.querySelector('csv-header-store-search').shadowRoot.querySelector('csv-header-modal').shadowRoot.querySelector('input').setValue('12345')");

Solution first not worked

2. I tried to use Tab and setValue

   browser.setValue('input', ['Tab'])
   browser.setValue('input', '12345')
3. Directly providing XPATH of that element is not working

Solution #2 also not worked

This is blocker for me now, Can someone please help me how to input text on shadow element.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Try the below.
`document.querySelector('cvs-header-desktop').shadowRoot.querySelector("cvs-header-store-search").shadowRoot.querySelector("cvs-header-modal").querySelector("input")`

[image]

Comment: You can find more details on how to work with ShadowDom - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow/56381495#56381495

Comment: How to setValue with this on the search input value?

Comment: will this work ? -   status=await driver.execute("document.querySelector('cvs-header-desktop').shadowRoot.querySelector("cvs-header-store-search").shadowRoot.querySelector("cvs-header-modal").querySelector("input").setValue('12345')");

Comment: setValue is not a function error with above code

Comment: For this code - document.querySelector('cvs-header-desktop').shadowRoot.querySelector("cvs-header-store-search").shadowRoot.querySelector("cvs-header-modal").querySelector("input") ....I am getting DevToolError...Element with Selector not found

Comment: It is returning element in console but when I am executing code in webdriver io its saying element not found with this selector @supputuri