# Unable to Find the Xpath for Google Home Page textarea or Input

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid, xpath-2.0

Unable to find the XPath for google home page - Search box.

1. Open the Chrome Browser
2. Inspect the default Google Search box on chrome browser
   [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGP6m.png)

Refer the image, we have to write the Xpath for Google textarea or search box

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath(//input[@id='input'])).sendkeys("testing");
```

Once we type the text in the search area, google will provide the suggestion based on text, we have to print the console suggested text.

I tried multiple ways to find the XPath but Match element not showing even element presence on webpage.

1. `By.Id('input');`
2. `By.Xpath("//input[@id='input']");`
3. `By.cssSelector("input#input");`
4. `By.Xpath("/html/body/ntp-app//div/div[1]/ntp-realbox//div/inputb");`

But Element not finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get it, because element is placed in shadow-root, which is placed in shadow-root.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)

Example of code in Java that reaches your input

```js
WebElement shadowRoot = driver.findElement(new By.ByTagName("ntp-app")); ;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement insideShadowInput = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('ntp-realbox').shadowRoot.querySelector('#input');", shadowRoot);
insideShadowInput.sendKeys("testing");
```